# Find modulus and argument of $\frac{1}{\omega}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find modulus and argument where $\frac{1}{\omega}=\frac{1}{z_1}+\frac{1}{z_2}$. Where am I supposed to start?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when $\text{z}_1\space\wedge\space\text{z}_2\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\left|\frac{1}{\omega}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\text{z}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{z}_2}\right|=\left|\frac{\overline{\text{z}_1}}{\text{z}_1\cdot\overline{\text{z}_1}}+\frac{\overline{\text{z}_2}}{\text{z}_1\cdot\overline{\text{z}_2}}\right|=$$
$$\left|\frac{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)\cdot i}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_1\right)}+\frac{\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)\cdot i}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)}\right|\tag1$$